# Can a c# timer call the .stop function on itself?

Tags: c#, .net, programming-languages

Whenever I try to do something like this the timer doesnt stop:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if ((addedToFriendsCounter == 4) || (followJobFinished))
        {
    //stop the timer
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, no problem.  A comment can't stop a timer.  Use

```
 timer1.Stop();
```

or

```
 ((Timer)sender).Stop();
```

Comment: +1 for `A comment can't stop a timer` :-) I spilled my beer on my screen when I read it, hilarious.

Comment: Also note that if the interval is small then it's good practice to stop the timer in the beginning of the tick function and then starting it at the end (in a finally block). Otherwise two ticks could overlap, if there was a slow database call or something like that.

Comment: 1 more question whilst on the subject..can i timer call thread.abort() on another running thread?

Comment: If it isn't working we might be able to help you if you post the complete timer1_Tick function that you have right now.

Comment: Don't *ever* call `Thread.Abort()`. It's pure, unadulterated evil.

Comment: You can do anything you want in a Tick event handler.  Avoid aborting threads.  Ask them to stop nicely with an AutoResetEvent.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem stopping the timer from within the `Tick` event handler. What the heck is `addedToFriendsCount` and `followJobFinished`? Your error is either with one of these or the code for `//stop the timer`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no problem stopping the timer from the `Tick` event. The event runs in the main thread, so there is no cross-thread problems when you access the `Timer` control.

You can stop the timer either by calling the `Stop` method or by setting the `Enabled` property to false.

Comment: and by that would that also imply the tiemr tick event can call thread.abort() on another thread which has started?

Comment: @brux: It could, but using `Abort` to stop a thread can cause problems. The thread will be stopped in the middle of whatever it's doing, so unless it's just waiting to be aborted, it's imnpossible to write code that handles the abort correctly.

Comment: Cross thread problems would depend on which Timer class is being used.  OP doesn't say.

Comment: @Robert Jeppesen: It's only the `Timer` for winforms and webforms that have a `Tick` event, and the one for webforms doesn't have a `Stop` method.